# Alert pop-up not showing

Tags: javascript, html, popup, alert

I can’t find the problem with my simple code. The button shows, but the alert pop-up doesn’t show when I click on it.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>


<body>
<h1>This will be a test for Javascript</h1>
<button> onclick=“myFunction()”>I like it</button>

<script>
 function myFunction() {
     alert(“are you sure?”);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You should include actual code in the question, rather than posting an image of it.

Comment: Turn off smart quotes in the editor you're using to program with. You have curly quotes in your HTML and Javascript, they don't work. It needs to be plain single quotes or double quotes.

Comment: From the look of it the problem is the use of actual quotes rather than quotation marks. That won't parse correctly.

Comment: debugging 101: browsers have a **developer** tools console - errors will be shown there, usually telling you exactly what you've done wrong

Comment: It seems to be `“`(smart quote) instead of `"`. Change it and check again. And open your browser's developer (usually <kbd>F12</kbd> and monitor the console tab. It will provide you some hints to correct your problem. When it comes to learning JavaScript, Browser console is your friend.

Comment: Always provide code as properly formatted text, not as a screenshot. I retyped the code, since this question makes a good duplicate target. There’s also another issue in your code: it’s `<!DOCTYPE html>`, not `<DOCTYPE! html>`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem in smart quotes.
Use

> **"**

quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button onclick="ok()">Ok</button>

<script>
function ok() {
    alert("ok");
}
</script>
```

Comment: What he needs is JavaScript. Not jQuery

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `""` not `“` in your code
2. Try to write your js code before html "button" code.
3. And try also to add a comma in the end of onclick script.