# Basic function JS not working

Tags: javascript, function

I'm looking for load a function while i click on a button.
I'm learning JS ...

```js
function changeStyle(){
    var paragraphe = document.getElementById('monParagraphe');
    paragraphe.style.backgroundColor="#000";
}
    
function load(){
    var buttonElt = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    buttonElt.addEventListener('click', changeStyle)
}
```

```html
<p id=’monParagraphe’>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
        elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat.
</p>

<button onclick=changeStyle()>Changer le style</button>
```

Comment: Use `id="monParagraphe"` instead of `id=‘monParagraphe’`.

Comment: You are binding the click listener twice. Either do the `load()` fuction or the `onclick=...`

Comment: my god ... i'm so stupid ! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Why are you getting those weird `’` instead of regular quotes? Are you writing your JS in Word?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [alert pop-up not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45852344/alert-pop-up-not-showing)

Comment: @JeremyThille Probably TextEdit on iOS.

Comment: Was an exercise from Mozilla CDN. I just copied the quote ... my bad

Answer (score 1):

Wrong tokens are used "".

```js
function changeStyle(){
    var paragraphe = document.getElementById('monParagraphe');
    paragraphe.style.backgroundColor="#000";
}

function load(){
    var buttonElt = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    buttonElt.addEventListener('click', changeStyle)
}
```

```html
<p id="monParagraphe">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat.
</p>

<button onclick="changeStyle()">Changer le style</button>
```